# Загрузка изображения PHP

Tags: php

Делаю проверку на изображение и ресайз, как после этого загрузить его в папку (mkdir)?

```
        $filename = $_FILES ["filename"]["tmp_name"];
        $size = getimagesize($filename);
        if ($size){
              $width = 150; 
              $height = 150;
              header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");
              list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);
              if ($width && ($width_orig < $height_orig)) { 
                    $width = ($height / $height_orig) * $width_orig; 
                } else { 
                    $height = ($width / $width_orig) * $height_orig; 
                } 
              $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
              imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
              imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100); 
              unlink ($filename);
              
              mkdir('../img/' . $id . '/', 0777, true);
              move_uploaded_file.....?

        } else {
              exit("Загружаемый файл не изображение..."); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно зачем ты пытаешься использовать `move_uploaded_file`, хотя на самом деле судя по логике тебе нужно в файл сохранить ресурс из первого аргумента `imagejpeg`.

Открываем мануал по `imagejpeg` и видим, что `imagejpeg` **умеет записывать в файл** ([пример 2](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php#refsect1-function.imagejpeg-examples)).

Следовательно что нужно сделать? Нужно в качестве второго аргумента передать нужный путь до файла:

```
  $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
  imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

  $dir = '../img/' . $id . '/';
  mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
  $newFileName = 'some_file.jpg';

  imagejpeg($image_p, $dir . $newFileName, 100); 

  unlink ($filename);
```

На этом все, никаких `move_uploaded_file` не требуется. Ставить `header` тоже ни к чему.